# RCON Get live data from gameserver

Tags: websocket, steam, rcon

I'm currently creating my own admin panel to control my Rust gameserver. Now I want to display real time data from the server like the player list, without polling the data in a fixed interval. Currently I'm using RCON over websockets, so it would be possible to receive live data, but I can't find any documentation for it.

I saw on BattleMetrics, that they display live data on their server pages, if the owner has the server connected via RCON. Then the data is shown live, according to a staff on discord. If they have no RCON connection, then the information is updated every 5 minutes. Sadly I can't use this API for the app I want to build.

Here is an example of a server that has RCON connected and shows live events, like which players left/joined the server recently: https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/rust/6803740

Real time updates explained in their docs:
https://learn.battlemetrics.com/article/47-webhooks#websockets

Does someone know if this is possible and could send me the docs for real time data fetching?

Comment: afaik RCON is TCP no? Live interval-less stream is suited to UDP. I'll be interested to know how this works out using a protocol that inherently doesn't support this without an interval.